# Update method not updating in CRUD application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, crud

I've made CRUD application with Java and MySQL, but it won't update.

- `StudentManager.displayAllStudents();` displays all students.
- Then with int `studentId = InputHelper.getIntegerInput("Select row to update: ");` I choose an ID of Sudent i want to update,
- and then with  `StudentManager.update(student);` it should update
  Student, but for some reason it doesn't

**This is helper class for inputs:**

```
public class InputHelper {

    public static String getInput(String prompt) {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print(prompt);
        System.out.flush();

        try {
            return stdin.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static double getDoubleInput(String prompt) {
        String input = getInput(prompt);
        return Double.parseDouble(input);
    }

    public static int getIntegerInput(String prompt) {
        String input = getInput(prompt);
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    public static Date getDateInput(String prompt) {
        String input = getInput(prompt);
        return Date.valueOf(input);
    }

    public static boolean getBooleanInput(String prompt) {
        String input = getInput(prompt);
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
    }
}
```

**This is Student manager class:**

```
public class StudentManager {

    private static final Student student = new Student();
    private static final Connection conn = DBConnectionUtil.getConnection();
    private static ResultSet rs = null;


      public static Student getRow(int studentId){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?";


        try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);){

            ps.setInt(1, studentId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){

                student.setStudentId(studentId);
                student.setFirstName(rs.getString(2));
                student.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
                student.setDateOfBirth(rs.getDate(4));
                student.setOnBudget(rs.getBoolean(5));
                return student;
            }else{
                System.err.println("No rows found");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            DBConnectionUtil.proccessException(ex);
        }finally{
            if(rs != null){
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                   DBConnectionUtil.proccessException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
    ........

    public static void update(Student student){
        String sql = "UPDATE student SET firstName = ?, lastName = ?, dateOfBirth = ?, onBudget = ? WHERE id = ?";
        try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);){

            ps.setString(1, student.getFirstName());
            ps.setString(2, student.getLastName());
            ps.setDate(3, student.getDateOfBirth());
            ps.setBoolean(4, student.isOnBudget());
            ps.setInt(5, student.getStudentId());

            int rowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(rowsUpdated > 0){
                System.out.println("User updated");
            }else{
                System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            DBConnectionUtil.proccessException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is main class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        StudentManager.displayAllStudents();


        int studentId = InputHelper.getIntegerInput("Select row to update: ");

        Student student = StudentManager.getRow(studentId);
        if(student == null){
            System.err.println("Row not found");
        }


         student.setFirstName(InputHelper.getInput("Enter new first name: "));
         student.setLastName(InputHelper.getInput("Enter new last name: "));
         student.setDateOfBirth(InputHelper.getDateInput("Enter new date of birth: "));
         student.setOnBudget(InputHelper.getBooleanInput("Is on budget? "));

         StudentManager.update(student);

    }

}
```

Comment: `it should update Student, but for some reason it doesn't` ... actually it _shouldn't_ update that `Student` object, it should update that student's particular database record.  Does the DB get updated?  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: did you get any error ? did you check your record in database, it updated or not?

Comment: With getRow I get the id of Student I want to update ..... then insert new first name, last name and other records, and then at the end when I call StudentManager.update(student); it should update Student with an id i choose with getRow method.

Comment: It prints out: "Something went wrong."  from update method in StudentManager class

Comment: can you print the `System.out.println(ps.toString());` before execute your update?

Comment: I changed my code in main class from:  
student.setFirstName(InputHelper.getInput("Enter new first name: ")); //etc

to: 


String firstName = InputHelper.getInput("Enter new first name: ");
        student.setFirstName(firstName);

And now update method works, DB is updated,  But I don't get it, what is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main class I changed the following....from:

```
  student.setFirstName(InputHelper.getInput("Enter new first name: "));
  student.setLastName(InputHelper.getInput("Enter new last name: "));
  student.setDateOfBirth(InputHelper.getDateInput("Enter new date of birth: "));
  student.setOnBudget(InputHelper.getBooleanInput("Is on budget? "));

  StudentManager.update(student);
```

To this:

```
    String firstName = InputHelper.getInput("Enter new first name: ");
    student.setFirstName(firstName);

    String lastName = InputHelper.getInput("Enter new last name: ");
    student.setLastName(lastName);

    Date dob = InputHelper.getDateInput("Enter new date ");
    student.setDateOfBirth(dob);

    boolean onBudget = InputHelper.getBooleanInput("Is on budget? ");
    student.setOnBudget(onBudget);


    StudentManager.update(student);
```

And now update method works, DB is updated, I can display changes.